# how can I use the title of an element as an id selector in jquery?

Tags: jquery, onclick, selector, title

what i am trying to do is when i click on the link, it will grab the title of the  then use it as an ID selector to call an element with the ID of #target to show. I have set the title of the link to be as such about and it is supposed to target a . My guess is that the data type is not the same so I cannot use the title directly as a ID selector? Please help or is there any better solution for this to be done?

```
$("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("title");
        alert(target);
        $("article").fadeOut("slow", function(){
            //animation completed
            $(target).fadeIn("slow");   
        });
    });
```

Comment: dont forget to marks answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you can do is

```
$("#" + target).function()
```

so you code will  be

```
 //animation completed             
 $("#" + target).fadeIn("slow");
```

As per the jQuery documentation "#" is id selector, so whenever you are try to access element by its id you need ot appedn "#" i.e you code will become

```
$("#"+ youid) or $("#elementid")
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make it into an actual `id` selector by concatenating it with a `#`:

```
$("#" + target).fadeIn("slow");
```

What you currently have is looking for elements whose tag name matches the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

if your title is missing the `#` character try instead

```
var target = "#" + $(this).attr("title");
```

and always check if the selector is not null before using with

```
if ($(target).length) {
    /* target exists */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[title='" + target +"']").fadeIn();
```